# why #control{} in CSS but not in html or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was going through this code for Codeplayer in Codepen (see link below), there is a ***#control{}*** listed in the CSS code but not mentioned in either HTML or JS code. Could anyone tell me why. Is this a mistake? I'm a newbie to web development so would really like to understand if this is standard or a trick... Thank you!

https://codepen.io/likezli/pen/dXPdJL

**CSS code:**

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    li {
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
    }

    a {
      color: black;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    #logo {
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
      float: left;
    }

    #menuBar {
      height: 40px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #EDEDED;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #buttonDiv {
      float: right;
      padding: 5px 15px 0 0;
    }

    #runButton {
      font-size: 110%
    }

    #control {}

    #toggleDiv {
      height: 40px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-top: 5px;
      position: relative;
    }

    #toggles {
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #toggles li {
      float: left;
      border-right: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 5px 8px 4px 7px;
    }

    .codeContainer {
      height: 100%;
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }

    .codeContainer textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: none;
      border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
      font-family: SourceCodeProRegular, Menlo, Monaco, consolas, monospace;
      font-size: 90%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 30px 0 5px 5px;
    }

    .codeLabel {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 10px;
    }

    #cssContainer,
    #jsContainer {
      display: none;
    }

    iframe {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .selected {
      background-color: #EAF3FF;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:visited {
      color: #000000;
    }

**here is the html code:**

        <div id="container">
      <div id="menuBar">
        <div id="logo">
          CodePlayer
        </div>

        <div id="buttonDiv">
          <button id="runButton">Run</button>
        </div>

        <div id="toggleDiv">
          <ul id="toggles">
            <a href="#">
              <li class="toggle selected">HTML</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="toggle">CSS</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="toggle">JS</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li class="toggle selected" style="border:none">Result</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="codeContainer" id="htmlContainer">
        <div class="codeLabel">HTML</div>
        <textarea id="htmlCode"><div id="test"></div></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="codeContainer" id="cssContainer">
        <div class="codeLabel">CSS</div>
        <textarea id="cssCode"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="codeContainer" id="jsContainer">
        <div class="codeLabel">Javascript</div>
        <textarea id="jsCode"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="codeContainer" id="resultContainer">
        <div class="codeLabel">Output</div>
        <iframe id="resultFrame"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

**JS Code:**

var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var menuBarHeight = $("#menuBar").height();

// code container height calculated
var codeContainerHeight = windowHeight - menuBarHeight;
$(".codeContainer").height(codeContainerHeight + "px");

// Toggling between HTML, CSS, JS and Output
$(".toggle").click(function(event) {
  // toggle items in menuBar
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");

  // get html of list item (html, css, js or result) in lowercase
  var activeDiv = $(this).html().toLowerCase();

  // combine it to one of the cor container id's (htmlContainer, cssContainer, etc.)
  // toggle show or hide
  $("#" + activeDiv + "Container").toggle();

  // count the container id's which are not hidden (display != none)
  var showingDivs = $(".codeContainer").filter(function() {
    return ($(this).css("display") != "none");
  }).length;

  // 100% width divided by active divs
  var width = 100 / showingDivs;

  // set the width
  $(".codeContainer").width(width + "%");

});

$("#runButton").click(function(event) {
  // find html tag in iframe and set this to html("text")
  $("iframe").contents().find("html").html('<style>' + $("#cssCode").val() + '</style>' + $("#htmlCode").val());

  // run javascript code in iframe
  document.getElementById("resultFrame").contentWindow.eval($("#jsCode").val());
});
```

Comment: it's an empty statement that will do nothing you can delete it if you want

Comment: If you can't see it,then maybe it is just an unremoved style

Comment: We can create styles whatever for id, or class in css,,,like you said #control{},,If there is any id or class assigned to tag / element, then only the styles gets reflected,,otherwise css wont applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create styles whatever for id, or class in css,,,like you said #control{},,If there is any id or class assigned to tag / element, then only the styles gets reflected,,otherwise css wont applied.